# Angular Reactive Forms data change validation not cosmetic change validation

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Given a particular formGroup and it's corresponding HTML form

```js
this.fieldForm = new FormGroup({
      fieldId: new FormControl(null),
      fieldName: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      sourceCreateBy: new FormControl(null),
      sourceUpdateBy: new FormControl(null),
    }, {validators: FieldFormValidators.invalidFormInput})  // some other logic
```

Consider the scenario that `fieldName` = "WORKFORCE". In the HTML Form, I edit the input field to make the value first "WORKFORCE_1" and then back to "WORKFORCE". The formGroup attributes have changed from `pristine=true, dirty=false, touched=false`  to `pristine=false, dirty=true, touched=true`.

Hence the form is valid. But actually no data change has taken place. Are there any inbuilt **FormControl** or **FormGroup** attributes or any combination thereof that can help me disable the "UPDATE" button or can I do such validation only after the fact(UPDATE button click)?

Can I create a custom validator to address this validation logic?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50405358/angular2-detect-if-data-in-an-angular-form-reactive-was-changed

Comment: @robert I Checked it out. But again it only deals with the cosmetic changes like `dirty, pristine, touched`. The other answer is that deals with validation after the fact in `submitForm()`. Thank you for your reply. You can check out the marked answer below to see what kind of solution I was actually looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom validator "isDifferent", but first reemplace the way to create the form using a function

```
getForm(data:any=null){
  data=data|| {fieldID:null,fieldName:"",sourceCreateBy:null,sourceUpdateBy:null}
  return FormGroup({
      fieldId: new FormControl(null),
      fieldName: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
      sourceCreateBy: new FormControl(null),
      sourceUpdateBy: new FormControl(null),
    }, {validators: [FieldFormValidators.invalidFormInput,isDifferent(data)]})
```

```
getForm(data:any=null){
  data=data|| {fieldID:null,fieldName:"",sourceCreateBy:null,sourceUpdateBy:null}
  return FormGroup({
      fieldId: new FormControl(data.fieldID),
      fieldName: new FormControl(data.fieldName, Validators.required),
      sourceCreateBy: new FormControl(data.sourceCreatedBy),
      sourceUpdateBy: new FormControl(data.sourceUpdateBy),
    }, {validators: [FieldFormValidators.invalidFormInput,isDifferent(data)]})  // some other logic

isDiferent(data:any){
   return (control:AbtractControl)=>{
     bool equal=true;
     Object.keys(data).forEach(key=>{
        equal=equal && data[key]==control.value[key]
     })
     return equal?{error:"must be different"}:null
   }
}
```

You use as

```
this.fieldForm=this.getForm(..your object...)
```

**Update**:Aclaration. Well the code above goes from I imagine a typical REST. So if we has a component to Edit/Create a register we has a router like

```
{ path: 'hero/:id',component: HeroDetailComponent },
```

Where, possible id values are a number or "new", so we can has

```
url=hero/new  //edit-component to create a new "hero"
url=hero/1    //edit-compoent to edit the hero with "id=1"
```

Our component, that has an form and use reactiveForm take account this, so

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,private service: HeroService) {}
form:FormGroup
status:string //here we store if "new" or "edit" to use for e.g.
              //the button "submit" show a message "create" or "update"
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
    switchMap(params => {
      const id=params.get('id')
      if (id=="new"){
          this.form=this.getForm();  //create a empty form
          this.status="new"
      }
      else{
         //use "+id" to convert to number the "id"
         this.service.getHeroe(+id).subscribe(res=>{
             //here we has the "data of the "hero"
             this.form=this.getForm(res)  //create a form with the data of hero
             this.status="edit"
         })
      }
  );
}
```

Our .html needn't a complex handlers in inputs, e.g. our button "submit" can be

```
<!--see that the button is disabled if the form is invalid
    if it's not invalid you need equal "disabled" to null,
    **not** to false
--->

<button disabled="form.invalid?true:null">
     {{status=="new"?"Create":"Update"}}
</button>
```

Comment: what data do I pass to `getForm()` function? Will I have to write custom event handlers on the inputs to call the `getForm()`? Because right now I only have to setup the `formControlName` directive in the HTML and then `fieldForm` is automatically updated.

Comment: @AyushNair, you're correct. The "code" goes from a more complex component. I added to the answer a little example in an imaginarium component to update/create a "hero". In the example you needn't write custom event handers

Comment: Your solution worked beautifully. Thank you so much. Only thing I changed was put the `isDifferent` method in a separate validator file. One more thing. From all those fields only fieldName is modifiable from HTML and the rest will be fixed programmatically using `patchValue()`. I can change the data object to be only `data = data || { fieldName: "" }`. This will make it more efficient I think. Shouldn't throw any issues right?

Comment: @AyushNair, Sorry ::glups::, there are a mistake in my code, see the updated  getForm function. So you understand that you need create on fly an object with all the properties